# Test main method without running the entire workflow

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-batch, code-coverage, test-coverage

We are using a spring batch application with multiple steps, launched from a main() method. The following code mimics the working:

```
public class SomeBatchLauncher{
    
    private static final String CONFIG = "application_context.xml";
    private static final String JOB_NAME = "springJob";

    public static void main(String args[]){
       launch();    
    }

    private static void launch(){
         // Load application context using CONFIG 
         // Launch the batch job using JOB_NAME 
    }
}
```

With this setup, I need write test cases and ensure maximum coverage. Everything but the main method is covered. How do I ensure coverage of main() method without triggering the entire batch to be executed?

I'm thinking of creating a test spring configuration XML with dummy jobs and changing the CONFIG and JOB_NAME variables using reflection before calling the main() from my test class. Is this a sound approach?

Comment: You can try Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils.setField`

Comment: Would it be reasonable to pass the value of `CONFIG` and `JOB_NAME` via the `args[]` into the main method? This would result in a little bit more code inside your `main` but then you could pass the testvalues from your Unit Tests without the need of Reflections or anything else.

Comment: `Everything but the main method is covered.`: That's already great. Do you really need to cover the main method? If it's only to have 100% test coverage, I believe that's not necessary (unless you have some logic that really needs to be tested in there, and in which case, you should extract it in a separate class and unit test that class).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. "ReflectionTestUtils.setField" did come in handy when I tried using reflection but involved a lot of changes for a single test case. Jan's advice is perfectly reasonable and it has been the way almost everywhere, well, except this place :(. Now, passing in values to main would need changes in job scheduler and we don't want to go that way. It so happens that every new line of code we add needs to be covered. Do you see any other option or refactoring is the only way out?